# React js hooks sets always one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**React js hooks sets always one step behind**
the first call appears as empty the second with the data,
I want the first call return the array.

```
const [test, setTest] = useState([])

async function array(){
    const array = [
      {id:1},
      {id:2},
      {id:3},
    ]
 setTest(array)
 console.log("ARRAY TEST",test)//the first call appears as empty the second with the data
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: I want the first call return the array

Comment: Well tough, basically!